# When is the localic reflection of a topos discrete?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Recall that the inclusion of locales into topoi has a left adjoint, called the localic reflection. It sends a topos $\mathcal{E}$ to the poset of subobjects of the terminal object, which is a locale. Is there are name for those topoi $\mathcal{E}$ whose localic reflections are discrete? Have they been studied?

Comment: The toposes with exactly two subterminal objects are sometimes called ‘two-valued’. There are quite a variety of these – gros toposes on $\mathbf{Top}$ or $\mathbf{Mfd}$, simplicial sets, realisability toposes...

Comment: Thanks Zhen. Do you have any references?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. Two-valuedness is not much studied. You might want to look into hyperconnected geometric morphisms (cf §A4.6 in [_Sketches of an elephant_]), since the first three examples I gave are hyperconnected over $\mathbf{Set}$. More generally, a topos defined over $\mathbf{Set}$ has the property you seek if and only if it is hyperconnected over $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ for some discrete $X$, but this is really just a paraphrase.